# Error Code 403 | Fetch Objects from iCloud Calendar through CalDAV | Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, icalendar, caldav

I am using Flutter and Dart in order to fetch Objects from my iCloud calendar through CalDAV protocol. I have already created an app-specific-password for my Apple account, indeed i am using that password in order to login, i am able to perform correctly every step inside the "Retrieving calendar information" section as shown in this [guide](https://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/), but i cannot proceed and fetch the objects as i am getting the error code 403.

> The 403 Forbidden error indicates that the server understands the
> request but can't provide additional access.

This is the code i am currently using. I am not sure if i had to include the c-tag inside the request or not.

This is the [official documentation of CalDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791).

```
Future<http.Response> fetchObjects() async {
  final request = http.Request(
    'REPORT',
    Uri.parse('https://pXXX-caldav.icloud.com:XXX/3XX91XX0X/calendars'),
  );

  request.headers['Authorization'] =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$appleId:$password'));
  request.headers['Depth'] = '1';
  request.headers['Prefer'] = 'return-minimal';
  request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8';

  final body = '''
    <c:calendar-query xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
    <d:prop>
        <d:getetag />
        <c:calendar-data />
    </d:prop>
    <c:filter>
        <c:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR" />
    </c:filter>
</c:calendar-query>
    ''';

  request.body = body;

  final response = await request.send();

  // Convert the StreamedResponse to a Response.
  final convertedResponse = await response.stream.toBytes();
  final parsedResponse =
      http.Response.bytes(convertedResponse, response.statusCode);

  print(parsedResponse.statusCode);
  print(parsedResponse.body);
  return parsedResponse;
}
```